# Angular 2. How interact between different level components?

Tags: angular

As far as I know there is numerous ways to interact between parent - child and child - parent components, like `EventEmitter` for example. But is there any way to interact between components that are not parent - child or child -parent relations, different from using Service for this purpose?

Comment: No, use a shared service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this class

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private emitter: EventEmitter<any>;
  constructor() {
    this.emitter = new EventEmitter<any>();
  }
  getEmitter(): EventEmitter<any> {
    return this.emitter;
  }
  emit(data: any): void {
    this.emitter.emit(data);
  }
}
```

and subscribe to event in components like

```
@Component({
 template: ''
})
export class MyComponent{
 constructor(private emitter: SharedService){
   this.emitter.getEmitter().subscribe(e => {
    // do stuff here
   });
 }
}
```

dont forget to add it to NgModule and use it as like services.